# seek better design to have multi-dispatching with java

Tags: java, design-patterns

In a language not supporting multiple dispatching, such as Java, the code would probably look something like this

```
/* Example using run time type comparison via Java's "instanceof" operator */
interface Collideable {
  void collideWith(Collideable other);
}

class Asteroid implements Collideable {
 public void collideWith(Collideable other) {
     if (other instanceof Asteroid) {
        System.out.println("AAAAAA");
     } else if (other instanceof Spaceship) {
        System.out.println("BBBBBB");
     } else if (other instanceof Plane) {
        System.out.println("CCCCCCC");
     } 
 }
}
class Spaceship implements Collideable {
 public void collideWith(Collideable other) {
     if (other instanceof Asteroid) {
         System.out.println("DDDDDDD");
     } else if (other instanceof Spaceship) {
         System.out.println("EEEEEEE");
     } else if (other instanceof Plane) {
        System.out.println("FFFFFFF");
     } 
 }
}
class Plane implements Collideable {
 public void collideWith(Collideable other) {
     if (other instanceof Asteroid) {
       System.out.println("GGGGGGG");
     }else if (other instanceof Spaceship) {
       System.out.println("HHHHHHH");
     }else if (other instanceof  Plane) {
       System.out.println("KKKKKK");
     }
 }
}
```

As the visitor pattern can help to solve this problem, I'm thinking if I should impl each leaf class with 
    void collideWith() {
       visitor.visit(this);  // visitor is set in the setter
    }

```
interface Visitor {
   void visit(Collideable c);
   void visit(Asteroid c);
   void visit(Spaceship c);
   void visit(Plane c);
}
```

Then each unique println should be implemented in subclass of visitor as below?

```
class AsteroidVisitor implements Visitor {
   void visit(Collideable c) {}
   void visit(Asteroid c) { System.out.println("AAAAAA"); }
   void visit(Spaceship c) { System.out.println("BBBBBBB"); }
   void visit(Plane c) { System.out.println("CCCCCC"); }
}
//etc for SpaceshipVisitor and PlaneVisitor()
```

Is it the best way to deal with this kind of refactoring to replace instanceof?

EDIT: The print out is just example of unique operations in each method, not the ultimate result. I modify my example to be clear.

Comment: Please format the code properly!

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: your modified example shows your "ultimate result"? I dont think so. please explain the rule, why is it  AAA ( BBB CCC DDD EEE )?

Comment: Because it's more structural refactoring I'm looking for, not simply constructing the string. The operation after each instanceof could be doThis(), doThat(), doThose(). I hope printing out distinct value will make my intention more clear.

Comment: @dave-jarvis Thanks. didn't know code review section exists

Answer (score 1):

In the example you gave you don't need two interfaces you only need the `Collideable` interface. The Collideable interface can be defined as follows:

```
interface Collideable {
  void collideWith(Collideable other);
  String getType();
}
```

Then `Spaceship`, `Plane`, and `Asteroid` would all implement `collideWith` and `getType`. As an example implementation, Spaceship's implementation would look like this:

```
class Spaceship implements Collideable {
 public void collideWith(Collideable other) {
     System.out.println(this.getType() + " collides with " + other.getType());
 }

 public String getType(){
   return "Spaceship";
 }
}
```

You can go one step further and declare Collideable as an abstract class, providing the implementation of collideWith since it is always the same. For example:

```
abstract class Collideable {
  void collideWith(Collideable other){
    System.out.println(this.getType() + " collides with " + other.getType());
  }
  String getType();
}
```

As a side note and general tip, your `Visitor` interface is poor design. The purpose of an interface is to define methods that **all** classes implementing that interface must provide a method definition (implementation) of. However your interface is very specific: it provides several types (`Spaceship`, `Asteroid`, etc) as method parameters. Therefore it is bad design, why did you even need that interface to begin with? It doesn't look like it can be used anywhere else.

Comment: Please look at the updated question. My question is more towards structure rather than string manipulation/output. Visitor pattern has to have visibility of concrete impl otherwise it won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Double dispatch has to do with method overloading. What you seem to be showing in your snippet is only reliant on single dispatch -- you have an interface, the implementation of which will be invoked at runtime.

As I see it, the real problem is that your `Collidable` interface should have a `getName` or `getType` method, which returns "asteroid" or "spaceship" or what have you, and then your implementation of `collidesWith` could simply print out its own name and its collision partner's name. I'm not seeing in this example where you would need double dispatch -- just a case of why `instanceof` is a code smell.

Comment: This seems method overloading on top of interface overwritting. If Java allowed multi-dispatching, then code doesn't need refactoring. I want to know if this is the best design we can do in java. The print is just an example be unique, not exactly the purpose. I can have unique string nothing to do with the name of class.

Comment: See @KyleM's answer. Your question is a good example of an [X/Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question right.

you could consider to add a method, something like:

```
interface Collideable {
    void collideWith(Collideable other);
    //new method
    String getSpecificStuff(); 
}

class Asteroid implements Collideable {

    String getSpecificStuff(){
        return "Asteroid";
    }
}
```

then method:

```
 public void collideWith(Collideable other) {
     System.out.println(this.getSpecificStuff() +" VS " + other.getSpecificStuff());
 }
```

the other subclasses just follow the rule like above.

Of course, these are just examples. you can implement your own `getSpecificStuff()` method with your real logic.

Code was not written in IDE, I say sorry if  there  are typoes or eye-hurting format.

Comment: I modified my example to be clear that printed result is not the focus. Thanks.

Comment: where does the `AAA,BBB,CCC.DDD...` come? is there any rule?