# functions with same names receiving instances of different derived classes

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a base abstract class and 2 extending classes:

```
public abstract class A {}
public class B extends A {}
public class C extends A {}
```

And then I have a main class with 2 similar functions, one that calls an object of type B, and one that calls an object of type C:

```
public class Manager {
    public void foo(B b) {}
    public void foo(C c) {}
}
```

Now, I want to do something like this, in class Manager:

```
public void bar(A a) {
     foo(a);
}
```

At this part, I'd expect Java to recognize if a is of type B or C, and accordingly call the relevant function - the one that accepts B as the argument, or the one that accepts C as the argument. But, this doesn't work. Instead, I have to do this -

```
if (a instanceof B) {
     foo((B)a);
} else {
     foo((C)a);
}
```

Am I missing something here? I notices that in all other places, Java knows very well which function to call, and I'm experiencing problems in this function call only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java only dispatches dynamically based on the object the method is invoked on (to select which class provides the method implementation). Dispatch based on argument types (necessary for overloading) is done statically, at compile-time.

Comment: Personally, I avoid overloading methods and give the methods different names. Since method dispatch between them does not work anyway (as you found out), better to avoid the potential for confusion.

Comment: yes, `instanceof` is probably a good solution. Another approach is the "ping-pong" scheme of moving the method to class `A`, `B`, `C` and doing the reverse call `a.foo(this)`. But that may not be appropriate design-wise.

Comment: There is also some discussion at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16112856/seek-better-design-to-have-multi-dispatching-with-java

Answer (score 0):

I guess that in that case Java cannot determine the method to call compile-time so it needs a cast (so a runtime check of the type) to resolve it.